# Elevation Check on Google Map using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

How can I find the elevation of particular land area in map using OpenLayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Google Service call for finding the elevation of the particular area in world

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have searched this same result somewhere else. Just now I got it. I wasted my past one year to find the answer for this silly question. Superb.